# No logcat output in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I recently switched to connecting to the phone via WiFi. I am able to compile and upload programs through Eclipse. However, I do not receive any logcat ouput. The phone is also shown in the DDMS view and when my program is started it also displays the name and pid. Is it possible to get the logcat trace via wireless or do I have to switch back to using a USB connection?

UPDATE:
Maybe I did not make it clear enough in my initial post. There is no problem with the connection itself. I can dump the logcat by using a terminal with 'adb logcat -d'. What I want is to see the live logcat in Eclipse's logcat viewer. Not sure if it is of any importance, but I am using Eclipse 3.8 in Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly happened, but it is working now. I did not do anything that I had not tried earlier. It just started working after several attempts. Might be a faulty Eclipse installation, it did crash earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

(1) connect phone with usb, then type in command line:

adb tcpip 5555

you can disconnect your phone from usb now

(if the reason for using wifi is that usb does not work on your machine, just do the above on another computer

(2) find out the IP address of your mobile device (somewhere under settings .... phone status)

(3) in command line type:

adb connect [IP of your mobile]

NOTE: all devices need to be connected to same wifi; avoid using public wifis

Answer (score 0):

In your eclipse,

just go to: windows->preferences->Android->logcat and follow the following setup:
1. double-click action: "go to problem (error line)
2. switch to: java
3. both checkboxes are checked

if setup is fine, clean the project and restart eclipse

Comment: There are no such settings in my Eclipse. I am using Eclipse 3.8, OS is Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Your ADB Server

1) open cmd

2) change directory to `platform-tools`

3)type `adb kill-server`

4)then `adb start-server`